# vertical aligning two pull-right elements of different heights (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float, vertical-alignment

I have two links (one text and one image) that I'm trying to **pull-right** and have the **bottom** of each vertically-align. But right now, it looks like this:

[image]
(vertically aligned with each others' tops)

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <div class="caption clearfix">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p class="thin">Donut jelly beans muffin cupcake. Oat cake caramels gingerbread cotton candy.</p>
            <p class="thin">Chupa chips biscuit jelly chocolate bar danish caramels sugar plum cupcake.</p>
            <a href="#" class="pull-right"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x70"></a>
            <a href="#" class="pull-right">See example</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how I would **vertically align to each elements' bottom**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to put both A elements in a div container, then float that div to the right.  From there, set the A elements to inline-block and vertical align: bottom.  Here is a working example:  http://jsfiddle.net/z26s7nb1/2/

```
<div class="col-md-7">
<div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="caption clearfix">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p class="thin">Donut jelly beans muffin cupcake. Oat cake caramels gingerbread cotton candy.</p>
        <p class="thin">Chupa chips biscuit jelly chocolate bar danish caramels sugar plum cupcake.</p>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <a href="#">See example</a><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x70"></a></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your CSS:

```
.pull-right
{
    float: right;

}
    .pull-right a
{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;    
}
```

Comment: I like this, though I would recommend offsetting your structure with a margin/padding as opposed to using floats. The consequence is insignificant, but still something to consider. Floating is particular developed for having paragraph text wrap around an image.

Comment: agreed!  Though my intent was to just stick with the basic layout given, with adding the vertical-alignment.  Still, I am with you when it comes to floats... I typically try to avoid them unless needed.